# QR codes are generated in first row only (Probably iteration problem in PHP)

Tags: php

I have following code to get data from MySQL, generate QR code based on link in column "URL" and display it. Everything is working fine, the only problem I'm not able to solve is, that all the QR codes (10 in this case) are displayed in the first row and the rest rows have no QR codes.

```
<script src="qrcode.min.js"></script>

<?php

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT objectid,code,url FROM stations LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

?>


<table>
<thead><tr><th> OBJECTID </th><th> CODE </th><th> URL </th><th> QR </th></tr></thead>


<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "<script>new QRCode(document.getElementById('qrcode'), '". $row[url] ."');</script>";
      echo "<tr><td>" . $row[objectid] . "</td><td>". $row[code] ."</td><td>" . $row[url] . "</td><td><div id='qrcode'></div></td></tr>";
        }
}
?>
</table>
```

The library used to generate QR code is [this](https://github.com/chillerlan/php-qrcode)

Answer (score 0):

(this is a comment, but space and formatting are limitted in the comments section)

> The library used to generate QR code is this

But nowhere in the code you've shown us is that library called ( `echo '<img src="'.(new QRCode)->render($data).'" alt="QR Code" />';` ) nor have you said how the code is included.

Since the column which *should* contain the QR image is only....

```
<td><div id='qrcode'></div></td>
```

I presume that this is handled by the Javascript included in the page. But you didn't tell us what that is / what it does.

What I do see here, is that you will have multiple elements with the same ID - which is a bit silly - IDs are supposed to be unique. You also need to look outside the div itself to find the data to be rendered in the div. A better approach would be.....

```
<td><div class='qrcode' data='$row[url]'></div></td>
```

Then you simply need to loop through the elements with class 'qrcode' and retrieve the data attribute to call the javasccript and inject the image.

You also haven't looked at the *many* warnings your code is generating. Note that in the above I have embedded the $row[] value in the string, whereas you are splicing strings: `<td>" . $row[url] . "</td`. In the context you are using, you should be quoting the addray index thus: `<td>" . $row['url'] . "</td`. After pausing, logging a problem then resuming execution, PHP will treat this as if it were quoted - but its very bad practice to write code this way and very, *VERY* bad not to check your logs.

Comment: Hi symcbean. Thank you. The script which generate qr code is above the div with id="qrcode". <script>new QRCode(document.getElementById('qrcode'), '". $row[url] ."');</script>. There is no other javascript code there. I'm afraid some mistakes was caused by the re-writing here, I'm sorry about that. However this is one-time script to generate QR codes which will be copied to documents and print. It's not for production web, but you're right about the bad practices of course :(